# gitlab api: how to retrieve userId of current user

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'd like to have a individually callable url to see issues in gitlab for a specific user.

How can I retrieve the currently logged in user?

https://server/folder/project/issues?scope=all&state=opened&assignee_id=`<how to get this id>`

or

https://server/folder/project/issues?scope=all&state=opened&assignee_username=`<how to get this name>`

Edit:

Solved with `scope=assigned_to_me`
https://server/folder/project/issues?scope=assigned_to_me&state=opened

Comment: [Gitlab Users API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html) provide methods to get these information. What more do you need ?

Comment: can you please indicate where exactly the api provides the method to get the userinformation (id or username) of the account which is being used to send the request? All I can find is 'id (required) - The ID of a user' - apparently I'm struggling with the 'required' part.

Comment: The Users API doesn't provide the information of the currently logged/authenticated in user

Comment: which of your comments is now correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[List current user](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#list-current-user-for-normal-users): Gets currently authenticated user.

```
GET /user
```

example: `https://gitlab.example.org/api/v4/user`.

Comment: cool - with a small script this can lead to a working solution. 
I'll mark as complete, as this answers how I asked the question. 
Nevertheless, it would be great to have a possibility to use a default id, which leads back to the real id, to use in filters (eg -1)

Comment: This answers the question "How can I retrieve the currently logged in user?". If you want to the the issues of a specific user, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html: there is a parameter `author_id`. There is also the parameter `scope`, to filter the issues *created_by_me* or *assigned_to_me*.